# PHP - Check $_POST after Submit => if values are the same as in database, redirect $_POST to another website

Tags: redirect, post, paypal

currently I'm trying to implement a function to let users Pay via PayPal on my Website (to unlock downloads for the commissions I'm doing).
So I've setup a HTML Form with some hidden inputs like price and stuff.
I want to check the $_POST after Submit on another php-script for modifications. And if the user has modified any of the entries, he should get a warning. If everything's fine, this $_POST should be redirected to PayPal like it usually does.

So I don't want to let a user modify the price-value or any other value (which the script gets from my database)-
When he clicks on "Checkout", the website opens a php-script that validates the values from $_POST with the Database.
When everything is fine, the $_POST should be redirected to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

any idea?

```
<?php
    echo '
    <form id = "paypal_checkout" action = "https://mywebsite/checkPOST.php" method = "post">
        <input name = "cmd" value = "_cart" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "upload" value = "1" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "no_note" value = "0" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "bn" value = "Get your commissioned Item" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "tax" value = "0" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "rm" value = "2" type = "hidden">

        <input name = "business" value = "commissions@mywebsite.de" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "handling_cart" value = "0" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "currency_code" value = "USD" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "lc" value = "DE" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "return" value = "http://mysite/myreturnpage" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "cbt" value = "Return to My Site" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "cancel_return" value = "http://mysite/mycancelpage" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "custom" value = "" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "unlockcode" value = "'.$unlockcode.'" type = "hidden">

        <div id = "item_1" class = "itemwrap">
            <input name = "item_name_1" value = "'.$row['name'].'" type = "hidden">
            <input name = "quantity_1" value = "1" type = "hidden">
            <input name = "amount_1" value = "'.$price.'" type = "hidden">
            <input name = "shipping_1" value = "0" type = "hidden">
        </div>

        <input id = "ppcheckoutbtn" value = "Checkout" class = "button" type = "submit">
    </form>';
?>
```

All in all, everything I want is to prevent users being able to modify this values before sent to paypal.

Comment: Can you create a `Cart` table in your database which holds all these values, then pass a `cart_id` around, rather than all of the values?

Comment: You can't technically keep people from modifying the html data. If you have data in your database to verify it against, you can check one of two ways. Perform a query to load all the data into an array, then check your `$_POST` against that array. Or create a query that checks all of the values directly.

Comment: Hey Reed, that's what I'm already doing.
The values are sent to another php-script via Submit.
There, all $_POST values are checked against the Array I got from my Database.

Here's the other script that checks the $_POST: https://pastebin.com/9sX31amZ

The checking stuff works, but I don't know how to redirect the $_POST to PayPal. 

Any idea?

Comment: Oh, okay! I'm not sure. It's been years since I've worked with Paypal. I'd imagine they would have pretty good documentation. They did back when I used it before.

Comment: Just found a method that seems to work x)
    $paypalUrl = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    $queryString = http_build_query($data);
    header('location:' . $paypalUrl . '?' . $queryString);
    exit();